# Flutter Android App hangs, while typing dot(.) in TextField

Tags: android, flutter

I have a very simple Flutter App for Android with following class. App hangs, as soon as I type a dot character followed by text in the TextField.

e.g.: venkata.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController emailIdController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: TextField(
            autofocus: false,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
              hintText: "Email Address",
              labelText: 'Email Address',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              )),
            controller: emailIdController,
          ),
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I am using Samsung m10s Mobile with latest firmware. It is running Android version 9.0. For other installed Apps on this Mobile, this kind of issue is not seen. So, I am thinking that some issue in TextField usage or issue in Flutter SDK.

Here is the Flutter version info

```
Flutter 1.15.22-pre.32 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision fd8b65e1bd (10 days ago) • 2020-03-15 23:26:01 -0400
Engine • revision 3e02f3bec9
Tools • Dart 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.14.0 eff5548a68)
```

The VS Code terminal starts printing errors continuously. Pasted below first few lines of errors. Appreciate, if I can get any suggestions to fix the issue.

```
D/ViewRootImpl@eb77dbe[MainActivity]( 1753): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@eb77dbe[MainActivity]( 1753): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/InputMethodManager( 1753): SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 1753 view : com.example.sample
D/InputMethodManager( 1753): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@5e90c72[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 1753): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager( 1753): Starting input: tba=com.example.sample 
ic=io.flutter.plugin.editing.InputConnectionAdaptor@9b32b88 mNaviBarColor -855310 
mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager( 1753): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager( 1753): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport( 1753): Input channel constructed: fd=101
D/InputTransport( 1753): Input channel destroyed: fd=93
D/InputMethodManager( 1753): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@5e90c72[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 1753): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
```

Comment: Maybe try another release channel? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels

Comment: Er1, With stable channel issue is not seen. Please post this as an Answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try another release channel? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels

Edit: Maybe file a bug report with your findings on there as well. ;)

Comment: Worked in stable channel. Also, in the latest release this issue is fixed.